# Bash: Removing empty or missing entries in associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I have an associative array, as below, with helpful suggestions from Stackoverflow community to build the arrays and have them behave in the order values are defined. i.e. Disks go into 'disks_order' in the order they are defined.

Everything is working well, until we encounter something that we don't expect. For example, if an entry is empty (noticed the line commented out). This throws everything out:

```
#!/bin/bash

localEndPoint="/tmp/test/"

declare -A disks

 disks=([0-UUID]=a6506a2c844b40cc [0-MountPoint]='/media/user/SomePath/')
disks+=([1-UUID]=a1f369ab35c5a22e [1-MountPoint]='/media/user/SomeOtherPath/')
disks+=([2-UUID]=6fd9ad56f4b94648 [2-MountPoint]='/media/user/AnotherOne/')
##disks+=([3-UUID]=aae8222d2ac131b0 [3-MountPoint]='/media/user/YetAnother/')  ## notice this line is commented out
disks+=([4-UUID]=0 [4-MountPoint]='/home/user/')
disks+=([5-UUID]=0 [5-MountPoint]='/home/user2/')


# build array so as to reflect the way it was defined above
# find total number of keys used and then use that for the division calculation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532910)
declare -A keycount; for i in "${!disks[@]}"; do keycount[${i//[0-9]-/}]=""; done
totalDisks=$((${#disks[*]} / ${#keycount[@]}))
x=1; while [[ $x -le $totalDisks ]]; do disks_order+="$(( x-1 )) "; x=$(( $x + 1 )); done # 'disks_order' array is used to process which disks are handled in what order

# list everything
for i in ${disks_order[*]}; do
    diskLabel=$( basename "${disks[$i-MountPoint]}" )
    printf "Point $(( i+1 ))"
        if [[ "${disks[$i-UUID]}" == 0 ]]; then
            printf ": Path "
        else
            printf ": Disk "
        fi
    printf "${disks[$i-MountPoint]} to ${localEndPoint}${diskLabel}/\n"
done
```

#### Actual output

```
Point 1: Disk /media/user/SomePath/ to /tmp/test/SomePath/
Point 2: Disk /media/user/SomeOtherPath/ to /tmp/test/SomeOtherPath/
Point 3: Disk /media/user/AnotherOne/ to /tmp/test/AnotherOne/
Point 4: Disk  to /tmp/test//
Point 5: Path /home/user/ to /tmp/test/user/
```

(notice the empty line for Point 4, and loss of /home/user2)

#### Desired Output

```
Point 1: Disk /media/user/SomePath/ to /tmp/test/SomePath/
Point 2: Disk /media/user/SomeOtherPath/ to /tmp/test/SomeOtherPath/
Point 3: Disk /media/user/AnotherOne/ to /tmp/test/AnotherOne/
Point 4: Path /home/user/ to /tmp/test/user/
Point 5: Path /home/user2/ to /tmp/test/user2/
```

So. How can I remove empty entries `disks_order`?

I suspect we need to revisit the solution from this answer re ["counting the total number of keys in an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532910)?

i.e.

```
declare -A keycount; for i in "${!disks[@]}"; do keycount[${i//[0-9]-/}]=""; done
totalDisks=$((${#disks[*]} / ${#keycount[@]}))
x=1; while [[ $x -le $totalDisks ]]; do disks_order+="$(( x-1 )) "; x=$(( $x + 1 )); done
```

Edit: `totalDisks` is needed to display total number of entries in array, to be used later in the script.

Comment: And you number elements manually? Didn't you think of doing it by itself?

Comment: it looks (to me) like you've assumed disk numbers are contiguous, but this goes out the window as soon as you remove one of the `disks[]` assignments; before the `for` loop add `typeset -p disks disks_order` to see the contents of the arrays and to see if they match up (index wise) the way you think they do

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to add discs that would number them auto....

```
declare -A disks
disks_add() {
   local n="$((${#disks[@]}/2))"
   disks+=([$n-UUID]="$1" [$n-MountPoint]="$2")
}
disks_add a6506a2c844b40cc '/media/user/SomePath/'
```

Remember to check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net

But I do not see any advantages in your design, just you add complexity with those `totalDisks` and `disk_order` stuff. I would just use two arrays:

```
disk_uuids=() disk_mountpoints=()
add_disk() { 
   # I am so lazy to type...
   disk_uuids+=("$1") 
   disk_mountpoints+=("$2")
}
add_disk a6506a2c844b40cc '/media/user/SomePath/'
# Who cares about indexes??
add_disk a1f369ab35c5a22e '/media/user/SomeOtherPath/'
add_disk 6fd9ad56f4b94648 '/media/user/AnotherOne/'

for ((i=0;i<${#disk_uuids[@]};++i)); do
    echo "Wow, so easy no sorting..."
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${disk_uuids[i]}" "${disk_mountpoints[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Hi there, this is insightful. Thanks. Please see my edit above though about `totalDisks`. Are you able to find `totalDisks` in your suggestion with this array build?

Comment: What does `totalDisks` represent? Those 3 lines in your script are totally unreadable to me.

Comment: The total amount of times we have done `add_disk a1f369ab35c5a22e '/media/user/SomeOtherPath/'` `add_disk 6fd9ad56f4b94648 '/media/user/AnotherOne/'` etc lines

Comment: That's just the count of elements in the array.....

Comment: ... and how do I do that, please?

Comment: ex. `${#disk_uuids[@]}` as in the loop. or `${#disk_mountpoints[@]}` fo the other array, they will have same count of elements. Would be nothing wrong with adding a `disk_cnt` variable and incrementing it too.